# Is there a list of all tags used on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

I wondered if there is a list of all tags used on stackoverflow.com. I wanted to browse the whole list and had to open the tag search and scroll through every page. Is there a site which lists all the tags or do I have to go through all the search result pages?

Comment: You mean like the [tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Data Explorer is the way to go:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1069131/get-all-tags

Note that since SEDE allows maximum of 50000 (50k) results per result set, and Stack Overflow got over 50k tags now, I had to split the query to return two result sets. To switch between the result sets, click the number in the header:

> [image]

One downside though, the data in there is not live so it means you won't see new tags created since last Monday.

Comment: Nice work! I needed a bit of additional data (usage counts and the tag description), so forked the query as https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/909710/get-all-tags-with-their-counts-and-descriptions

Comment: How can I get a list like that for ham.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @MikeWaters there is "Switch sites" textbox, just type and select the site you want, then after the page reloads run the query. Direct link to save you those steps: https://data.stackexchange.com/ham/query/172362/get-all-tags

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there a way to filter out tags with more than N questions? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out, here it is https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/969570#resultSets